# C# OLEDB Command Timeout Does Not Work

Tags: c#, ado.net, timeout, oledb

```
using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnString))
        {
            Conn.Open();                
            OleDbCommand odbCmd = new OleDbCommand(strQuery, Conn);
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = odbCmd;
            odbCmd.CommandTimeout = 10;
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
```

The query I pass takes about 1 minute to execute and fill the data table but the command does not timeout after 10 seconds as specified.

*My Objective is to throw an error to the user when he tries to fetch huge data from Oracle data base (using my website) that takes more time*. Is there any other effective way I can acheive that or Am I missing something in the above code?

Comment: how are you measuring the time,when you say it executes in 1 minute

Comment: @user841311, what is the database ? is it oracle ?

Comment: @CodeIgnoto I didn't use stopwatch to measure time but I see that at run time, it's definetely taking more time than 10 seconds. I also inserted a debug point at the time of filling data table and see that it's taking more than 10 seconds.

Comment: @Habib, yes it is oracle. Edited my question with that.

Comment: I think its an issue with the oracle, you may see: http://forums.asp.net/t/1402743.aspx/1?OledbCommand+TimeOut+Property+not+working

Comment: @Habib, I have Oracle 10.2.0.4 so may be that doesn't support timeout property..Any other way to implement this?